# rdsserver.datafactory converttostring failure

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, vbscript

I have a classic ASP application written many years ago that I'm trying to fix.

The following lines recently stopped working after w7 sp1 was applied.

```
set address  = Server.CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
count = lo_connection.GetRecordset(sql,address,false, error)
Set RDF2 = Server.CreateObject("RDSServer.DataFactory")
Set teststring = RDF2.ConvertToString(address)
```

It fails on the last line there saying "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Class doesn't support Automation"

A bit of searching found several articles like this one

http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/03/14/changes-in-mdac-adodb-com-components-in-windows-7-service-pack-1.aspx

that described the problem exactly.  Where I am failing is that none of the suggested fixes seems to fix the problem.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions described in the link are not relevant here, since ASP is not early-bound - it uses OLE Automation. It might be worth re-registering the component which creates RDSServer.DataFactory objects (which is C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\msadc\msadcf.dll on my machines).

I looked up this object, and I found this Microsoft web page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681447(v=vs.85).aspx

"This feature will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Applications that use RDS should migrate to WCF Data Service."

Doesn't sound too good.

Comment: hey Mark, thanks for pointing that out, you are correct in my link not being relevant.  Unfortunately the company I'm doing this for doesn't have the option of changing that particular area out since part of the application that uses this they no longer have the source for.  I need to figure out why this isn't working.